# How to isolate / confine / contain a new font inside of a \NewEnviron (new environment using eviron package))

Tags: fonts, environments

I have a situation here. I am designing an IPA Vowel Chart and I have created a new font environment for the IPA characters using the IPA font *Doulos SIL* like this: **\newfontfamily{\ipafont}{Doulos SIL}**

Now I would like to use this command in the title to write "IPA" phonetically in the IPA alphabet inside of **\NewEnviron{heading}** using the *environ* package (found just before *\begin{document}*).

**Problem**
Upon adding the **\ipafont{}** command to a line, instead of the brackets containing the font to be changed, the command simply applies itself to the rest of the line, messing up my nice title. See the code and picture below:

```
%%% -*- mode:latex; mode:font-lock; -*-
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
%HEADER FOOTER
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{\textsc{Sounds in American English}} \chead{\textsc{}} \rhead{\textsc{} 
\lfoot{\textsc{created on \today \space \currenttime}} \cfoot{\textsc{}}} \rfoot{\textsc{-\thepage-}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}%ADD HEADER FOOTER TO PAGE EXCEPT TITLE PAGE
%USE THISPAGESTYLE{EMPTY} BELOW MAKETITLE OR {FANCY}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{vowel}
\usepackage{soul} % use this (many fancier options)
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}
\newfontfamily{\ipafont}{Doulos SIL}%ADD FONT IN PREAMBLE, USAGE IN BODY: \otherfont{some text}
%OR {\fontspec{Zapfino} different text} IN BODY FOR ONE-TIME USE


%HIGHLIGHTER CODE
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{btHighlight}[1][]
{\begingroup\tikzset{bt@Highlight@par/.style={#1}}\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
{\end{lrbox}\bt@HL@box[bt@Highlight@par]{\@tempboxa}\endgroup}

\newcommand\btHL[1][]{%
  \begin{btHighlight}[#1]\bgroup\aftergroup\bt@HL@endenv%
}
\def\bt@HL@endenv{%
  \end{btHighlight}%   
  \egroup
}
\newcommand{\bt@HL@box}[2][]{%
  \tikz[#1]{%
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}{\pgfpoint{\wd #2}{\ht #2}}%
    \pgfusepath{use as bounding box}%
    \node[anchor=base west, fill=orange!30,outer sep=0pt,inner xsep=0.2em, inner ysep=0.1em,  #1]{\usebox{#2}};
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\tikzhighlight}[2][red]{%
  {\btHL[fill=#1!10,draw=#1,rounded corners]#2}%
}


\newcommand{\BlankCell}{}
\newcommand{\ex}[1]{\small{\tikzhighlight[blue]{#1}\hspace{.5em}}}
\newcommand{\oex}[1]{\small{\tikzhighlight[yellow]{#1}\hspace{.5em}}}
\newcommand{\vl}[1]{\Large{[\ipafont{#1}}]}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{heading}{\begin{figure}[h!]\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,background rectangle/.style={fill=white!05},framed]\node  {\BODY};\end{tikzpicture}\end{figure}}


\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
% \nopagebreak[4]
\begin{landscape}
\begin{heading}
\Large IPA [\ipafont{aɪ pʰiː eɪ}] Vowel Chart for\\\Large Californian English
\end{heading}
    \begin{center}
    {\vowelhunit=8.5em
        \begin{vowel}
            %\putcvowel[l]{i}{1}
            \putvowel[l]{\vl{i} \ex{b\textbf{ea}d}}{0pt}{0pt}
        \putcvowel[r]{\vl{y} \ex{\st{f\textbf{üh}len}}}{1}
        \putcvowel[l]{\vl{e} \ex{b\textbf{ay}ed}}{2}
        \putcvowel[r]{\vl{ø} *}{2}
        \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ɛ} \ex{b\textbf{e}t,b\textbf{e}d}}{3}
           \putcvowel[r]{\vl{œ} *}{3}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{a} *}{4}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{ɶ} *}{4}
        \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ɑ} \ex{p\textbf{o}d}}{5}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{ɒ} *}{5}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ʌ} \ex{b\textbf{u}d}}{6}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{ᴐ} \ex{b\textbf{o}y (diphthong)}}{6}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ɤ} *}{7}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{}o \ex{b\textbf{o}de}}{7}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ɯ} *}{8}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{u} \ex{b\textbf{oo}ed}}{8}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ɨ} *}{9}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{ʉ} *}{9}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ɘ} *}{10}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{ɵ} *}{10}
            \putcvowel{\vl{ə} \ex{\textbf{a}bout,\textbf{a}bove}}{11}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{ɜ} \oex{b\textbf{u}st} *}{12}
            \putcvowel[r]{\vl{ɞ} *}{12}
            \putcvowel[l]{\vl{I} \ex{b\textbf{i}d}}{13}
           \putcvowel[r]{\vl{Y} *}{13}
            \putcvowel{\vl{ʊ} \ex{g\textbf{oo}d}}{14}
            \putcvowel{\vl{ɐ} *}{15}
            \putcvowel{\vl{æ} \ex{b\textbf{a}d}}{16}
        \end{vowel}
            }%
    \end{center}
\tikzhighlight[blue]{CA English} \hspace{.5em}\tikzhighlight[green]{OH English}
\end{landscape}
\section*{Vowels}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l}
/i/ as in seat \\
/ɪ/ as in sit \\
/eɪ/ as in cake \\
/ɛ/ as in met \\
/æ/ as in cat \\
/ɑ/ as in father \\
/ə/ as in bun \\
/ɔ/ as in law \\
/oʊ/ as in boat \\
/ʊ/ as in wood \\
/u/ as in two \\
/ər/ as in heard \\
/aɪ/ as in mine \\
/aʊ/ as  in mouse \\
/ɔɪ/ as in boy \\
\end{tabularx}  
\end{document}
```

[image: IPA Vowel Chart]

Comment: I don't see the messed up part in the picture. What is it?

Comment: `\small`, `\Large` and `\ipafont` are not commands with an argument, but declarations: so `{\ipafont #1}`, for example, not `\ipafont{#1}`. The same for `\small` and `\Large`

Comment: The messed up part is in the title "Vowel Chart for"

Comment: Thanks egreg for the info. Could you please tell me how to isolate a declaration?

Comment: As @egreg said: Use `{\ipafont aɪ pʰiː eɪ}`. Curly braces limit scope, brackets do not. I'd also advise to slip a `\par` somewhere in the node, because your use of `\Large` messes up the like skip, but I don't know where it is allowed...

Comment: Let me clarify—after egregs wonderful tip, I immediately did {\ipafont aɪ pʰiː eɪ} and I got the same results, before reading your comment. I made a typo and corrected it, now it works great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Commands such as the standard `\small` and `\Large`, but also your font selection command `\ipafont` are not commands with an argument (similarly to `\textbf`, to make an example).

So your commands must be defined differently:

```
\newcommand{\ex}[1]{{\small\tikzhighlight[blue]{#1}}\hspace{.5em}}
\newcommand{\oex}[1]{{\small\tikzhighlight[yellow]{#1}}\hspace{.5em}}
\newcommand{\vl}[1]{{\Large[{\ipafont #1}]}}
```

In the last command, for instance, `\vl{x}` will be replaced by

```
{\Large[{\ipafont x}]}
```

where the outer pair of braces isolates the `\Large` declaration, the inner one isolates the `\ipafont` font selection. Thus `x` will be printed in "Large" size and Doulos SIL, while the brackets will be in the main document font.

The same for the code

```
\begin{heading}
\Large IPA [\ipafont{aɪ pʰiː eɪ}] Vowel Chart for\\\Large Californian English
\end{heading}
```

which should be

```
\begin{heading}
\Large IPA [{\ipafont aɪ pʰiː eɪ}] Vowel Chart for\\Californian English
\end{heading}
```

There's no need of braces to isolate `\Large`, because an environment forms a group that bounds the action of declarations.

If you prefer a command for selecting Doulos SIL like `\textbf`, then issue in your preamble the code

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textipa}{\ipafont}
```

and then you'll be able to write

```
\textipa{aɪ pʰiː eɪ}
```

whence only the argument will be typeset in Doulos SIL with no leaking.

Actually, I don't see much sense in embedding the contents of `heading` as a single `\node` in a `tikzpicture`. Moreover, using a `figure` environment for it is surely wrong. Just say

```
\newenvironment{heading}
   {\begin{center}\Large}
   {\end{center}}
```

and now

```
\begin{heading}
IPA [{\ipafont aɪ pʰiː eɪ}] Vowel Chart for\\Californian English
\end{heading}
```

will give the correct result (with a correct distance between the two lines which is not obtained in a `\node`).

However, if you really need the `tikzpicture` and this is only a simplified version, *don't* use `figure`, but `center`.

Comment: I know that's not strictly what's asked, but maybe you could comment on the fact that `\Large foo\\bar` without a `\par` inside the same group is not a good idea?

Comment: @StephanLehmke In this case it doesn't make any difference, as the text is passed on to `\node`. But your comment is quite useful.

Comment: And does `\node` add a `\par` without wrapping the text in a group first? The two heading lines look awfully cramped on the example...

Comment: @StephanLehmke Yes, they are wrong, but `\node` doesn't produce paragraphs, AFAIK. So adding `\par` doesn't help. I've added something to my answer.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the attention to detail! The reason I use a tikzpicture environment is because I often give the title (along with other information at the top) a colored background box. having it in a tikzpicture is nice, because i can just change the "fill=white!05" to "fill=yellow!05", for example and vuala.

Comment: @macmadness86 So probably a `tabular` inside `heading` is better to ensure correct spacing between lines.

Comment: As it turns out, I need the title to be cramped, in order to keep the actual vowel chart large and everything on one page. Sacrificing a tiny bit of space in the title is worth it! (But I I will remember the "proper" way to do this in the future)--thanks